# C++ Win32 Draw to a DC and Keeping It

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I am trying to draw a simple few rectangles and store the result, I only need to draw it once. So, keeping the HDC (hdcBackround) at the top "globaly."

```
void drawBackground(HWND hwnd) { // hwnd is the main windows handle
 // dimensions
 RECT rect;
 GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);  
 HDC hWinDC = GetDC(hwnd);


 hdcBackground = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hWinDC); // "global"
 HBITMAP hbm = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWinDC, rect.right, rect.bottom);
 ::SelectObject(hdcBackground, hbm);

 SetBkMode(hdcBackground, TRANSPARENT);
 SelectObject(hdcBackground, hFont[HF_DEFAULT]);
 SelectObject(hdcBackground, hBrush[HB_TOPBG]);
 SelectObject(hdcBackground, hPen[HP_THINBORDER]);

 // draw
 Rectangle(hdcBackground, 0, 0, rect.right, 20);
 SelectObject(hdcBackground, hBrush[HB_LOWBG]);
 Rectangle(hdcBackground, 50, 20, rect.right, 40); 


 // ??? clean up after it works
 ReleaseDC(hwnd, hWinDC);
}
```

I call that function once, and in a timer I BitBlt() hdcBackground to the screens HDC. When I test it out, it draws both the rectangles, with a 1px border (as the pen is set as,) but there is no color, it is just black and white.

The brushes and such are all fine, it is just that I am not getting color. The RGB on the brushes are (25,25,25) and (65,65,65), dark grey.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you actually drawing to the window? The code you have posted only renders to an off-screen bitmap.

Comment: It is created like a normal window:
`code`
     hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
         0,
         g_szClassName,
         "Time Keep Two",
         //WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,WS_DLGFRAME
        WS_POPUP | !WS_BORDER | !WS_CAPTION | !WS_HSCROLL | !WS_VSCROLL,
        //CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        380, 0, 720, 40,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
`code`
I have it so that it is just a solid color/ pane, as I am wanting to store the "drawn" background in a HDC, and BitBlt it on the timer. The uses of hwnd all refer to the handle the window creation returns.

Comment: I didn't ask how you created the window, I asked how you are drawing to the window. Show your code.

Comment: Your problem description sounds like your first parameter to `CreateCompatibleBitmap` is `hdcBackground`. Did you post the exact code you are using? Also, `GetWindowRect` returns screen space coordinates; `rect.right` is not the same as the width. You probably meant to call `GetClientRect`.

Comment: Yeah, thats the exact code, and I fixed the GetClientRect. Same result. I do use in a few parts SetWindowPos and I have 2 push buttons added as well.

`case WM_PAINT: {
            
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
             
paintScreen(hwnd); 
                    
} break;

case WM_TIMER: {
paintScreen(hwnd);
} break;`

`void paintScreen(HWND hwnd) {
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
       
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(hwnd);
BitBlt(hdcScreen, 0, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, hdcBackground, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcScreen);
}`

Comment: HDC hdcBackground; // Global

`void drawBackground(HWND hwnd) {
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);  
HDC hWinDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    
// set it up
hdcBackground = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hWinDC);
HBITMAP hbm = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWinDC, rect.right, rect.bottom);
SelectObject(hdcBackground, hbm);`

Continued next comment.

Comment: `// objects
SetBkMode(hdcBackground, TRANSPARENT);
SelectObject(hdcBackground, hFont[HF_DEFAULT]);
SelectObject(hdcBackground, hBrush[HB_TOPBG]);
SelectObject(hdcBackground, hPen[HP_THINBORDER]);

// draw
Rectangle(hdcBackground, 0, 0, rect.right, 20);
SelectObject(hdcBackground, hBrush[HB_LOWBG]);
Rectangle(hdcBackground, 50, 20, rect.right, 40); 
      
// finish
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hWinDC);
}`

So, any ideas? I may have messed up the WM_PAINT... The goal I am going for is to have what I drew in hdcBackground, so that I can BitBlt it when needed, instead of redrawing.

Thanks.